# How to Use this Actionscript 3.0 code for several frames?

Tags: android, actionscript-3, ios5, flash-cs5

I'm completely new to Actionscript. I've searched everywhere for a screen orientation code but couldn't find a proper one. I'm trying to make a book app with several pages (frames) which has both portrait & landscape mode.

I found a code written by Adam Khoury but it only works with one frame. Is there any way to use this code with several frames (pages) with different movie clips? Here is a video of him using this code: [goo.gl/T24ku](http://goo.gl/T24ku).

```
// AS3.0 Android App View Modes Script For App View Orientation
// Written by Adam Khoury
import flash.display.Stage;
import flash.display.StageAlign;
import flash.display.StageScaleMode;
import flash.events.Event;
// Create stage instance and manipulate 2 of its properties
var appStage:Stage = myApp.stage;
appStage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE;
appStage.align = StageAlign.TOP_LEFT;
// Function that executes each time a phone or device is rotated
function orientateMyApp(event:Event):void {
    var device_width:int = appStage.stageWidth;
    var device_height:int = appStage.stageHeight;
    // Condition that allows toggling between view modes
    if(device_width > device_height){
        myApp.gotoAndStop("wide_view");
    } else {
        myApp.gotoAndStop("tall_view");
    }
}
// Add an event listener for the resize event of the stage instance
appStage.addEventListener(Event.RESIZE, orientateMyApp);
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using frames on the timeline for each layout, create each layout as its own movieclip, then put them both on one single frame.  Use the visible property to show/hide them.  As you flip through pages, advance both layout modes at the same time, or store the currentPage to set the layout after rotation.

```
if(device_width > device_height){
    //landscape mode
    landscapeView_mc.visible = true;
    portraitView_mc.visible = false;
} else {
    //portrait mode
    landscapeView_mc.visible = false;
    portraitView_mc.visible = true;
}
```

Comment: Thank a lot for your reply, I've got two questions,

1. How would I navigate to other MCs with swipe gesture since they are all in one frame.
2. Since it is a book, it will have tons of pages, even though only the mentioned (true) mc will be drawn but won't it have any memory issues, other way of asking is does "false" only make it invisible or it also makes it not load in memory?

Comment: I'd really appreciate if you could give me a visual example if possible. Since I'm new to this, it is hard for me to understand what you meant by "As you flip through pages...rotation."

Comment: Before I elaborate, can you shed a little more light on your knowledge of Flash in general?  In order to give you a helpful answer that is not a full on step by step tutorial on creating an application in Flash I need to know if you know the basics; creating movieclips that can be accessed by code, timeline navigation, events, classes, etc..

Comment: I apologize for being a bit vague, frankly speaking I'm very new to AS3 and Flash. However, I do know the basics of Flash (AS3, not much), make movie clips, instance names (to control MCs in AS3), basic codes that are in Code Snippets panel etc. I don't know how to incorporate things like functions, classes & event-listeners but I know a bit about their concept.

All this time I've been trying to use the code mentioned on my 1st post on every Frames (pages for my book). Unfortunately it gives me Error #1009.

Comment: Ok so today I thought I would actually post the test file: http://goo.gl/eh3W0

I'm getting this error whenever I try to test the movie:
 Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
 at Book_fla::MainTimeline/orientateMyApp()[Book_fla.MainTimeline::frame1:21] 

This template is really easy for me to use because I'll be able to visually change/add stuff on both orientations.